# Как получить символы из строки (все символы по отдельности)?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть такой вопрос как получить символы из строки? 
 Пример: Пользователь вводить text; нужен в таком варианте в массиве(или в переменный) `['t', 'e', 'x', 't']`.

Я пробовал такой вариант:
 JS код:

```
  let text = document.getElementById('IdName').value;
    let letter=text[2];

    alert(letter);
```

И так далее

и HTML код:

```
<input id="IdName">
```

Но тогда кода будет очень много и это мучительно. Как можно сделать такое? С меньшим количеством кода?

Зачем это нужно?В университете дали такую задачу(похожую, есть другие легкие варианты которые можно решать, но там для нескольких случаев). Хочу делать который работает в всех случаях..
Вообще не нравиться программы университета. Вообще бесполезные заданию дают. Которые в реальном проекте не нужны..

Comment: для чего это нужно?

Comment: Да почему такой программа нужен?7 В университете дали такую задачу(похожую) Вообще не нравиться программы университета. Вообще бесполезные заданию дают. Который в реальный проекта не нужны.

Comment: Вы что думайте я не предлогал? И ещё надо для таких задач чертит блок-схему и тестовый вариант в экселе (короче, то что делает мой код, надо и это делать в экселе, там очень мучительно) А еще не говорил.. Надо  в ПИ делать код в тетераде и показать что там правильно написано

Comment: @Сардар Атабеков  А куда делся мой принятый ответ на вопрос о цикле?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split('')` я только одного не понимаю, смысл этой задачи если строка и так является массивом.

```js
var splitTxt = document.getElementById("split");
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function()
{
  console.log(splitTxt.value.split(''));
});
```

```html
<input id="split">
<a id="submit">Подтвердить</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```js
 let text = document.getElementById('IdName').value;
 
 var text_arr = [];
 
 for (i = 0; i <  text.length; i++){
   let letter = text[i];
   
   text_arr[i] = text[i];
   
 }
   
console.log(text_arr);
```

```html
<input id="IdName" value="TEST">
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант:

```js
var text = "Some text",
    l    = text.length, 
    textArr = new Array();
    
for (var i=0; i<l; i++){
  textArr.push(text.charAt(i));
}

console.log(textArr);
```